# WPF Textbox : two textboxes, one need keybord focus and other needs selection of text using mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

In User control,I have two textboxes

Textbox1 - readonly

Textbox2 - editable and it has focus now with code bellow

```
 editableTextbox.CaretIndex = editableTextbox.Text.Length;
 editableTextbox.Select(0, editableTextbox.Text.Length);
 editableTextbox.Focus();
```

As per current code when user selects data for readonlyTextbox , focus from editableTextbox is gone.

I tried other way in which editable text box keeps focus but then user not allowed to select the data in readonlyTextbox. SO I think at a time only one textbox is keeping focus

Requirement is : when user select text from readonlyTextbox using Mouse, user should allowed to enter text in editableTextbox with keyboard.

Comment: There can be only one element on the whole desktop that has keyboard focus.

Comment: Does that mean when I select in readonlyTextbox with mouse it will also receive a keyboard focus?

Comment: Yes, it does. ......